# How to append a key to the beginning of json

Tags: php, json

Here is an example of what I need. I need to append the `results` key at the beginning of my json results

**JSON**

```
{
  "results": [ <-- this is what I need
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

**PHP**

I am creating my json results as such with php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";   
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);
$i = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $response[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $response[$i]['text'] = $row['text'];
    $data['posts'][$i] = $response[$i];
    $i++;
}
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo '[]';
} else {
    echo json_encode($data['posts']);
}
```

Which produces

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
]
```

How can I add that `results` key to my JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap this line `echo json_encode($data['posts']);` with an extra level of array index e.g **results**. Let's do it this way-

```
echo json_encode(['results'=>$data['posts']]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with the key above `json_encode`

```
$result = array('result'=>$data['posts']);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could also build the array that way in the loop:

```
$data['posts']['results'][$i] = $response[$i];
```

But to shorten the whole thing, just select what you want:

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `text` FROM `table`";   
$result = $GLOBALS['db']->query($sql);

while($data['results'][] = $result->fetch_assoc());
echo json_encode($data);
```